# Files -- does not proceed to get input

Tags: c, file, input

I have a test tomorrow and files confuse me a lot. This code I wrote stops at fscanf(f1, "%d", &n); and does not take any input in. I followed the teacher's example when coding this. Does any one have any idea why this happens? Also, is F2 completely necessary? The teacher's practice questions say to open up the file in read, read everything, keep a running total of all the wages earned, then once the reading is complete, prompt for an output filename string, open it, and write to the average value of all the earnings. I understand fprintf and fscanf to an extent, and the difference between read and write mode, however, I do not understand why F2 is necessary? He uses F2 in a similar example that used different variable names. Thanks in advance.

```
  #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
        FILE *f1;
        FILE *f2;
        char name[30];
        char name2[30];
        float wage;
        float wage_total;
        int n;
        int SSN;


        printf("What is the file name?\n");
        scanf("%s", name);

        f1 = fopen(name, "r");

        printf("What is the file name for F2?\n");
        scanf("%s", name2);
        f2 = fopen(name2,"w");

        int i;
        wage = 0;

        fscanf(f1, "%d", &n);

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            fscanf(f1,"%d", &SSN);
            fscanf(f1, "%f", &wage);
            wage_total += wage;   
        }
        fprintf(f2,"%f", wage_total);
        fclose(f1);
        fclose(f2);

        system("pause");
        return 0;
        }
```

Teacher's Example:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main() {
     FILE*  fp1;
     FILE*  fp2;
     int n;
     int i;
     int id,len,width;char word[30],word2[30];
     printf("type input fname:");
     scanf("%s",word);
     printf("type output fname:");
     scanf("%s",word2);
   fp1 = fopen(word, "r");
   fp2 = fopen(word2,"w");


     fscanf(fp1,"%d", &n);
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {  fscanf(fp1,"%d%d%d", &id, &len, &width);
         if ( (len*width) > 500)
          printf("%d %d %d", id, len, width);
      }
   fclose(fp1);
   fclose(fp2);
   system("pause"); return 0;
   }
```

Comment: You will invoke *undefined behavior* if positive number is read to `n` because value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration `wage_total`, which is indeterminate, is used.

Comment: `f2` in this code is not necessary. You can open the output file and assign its file pointer to `f1` after closing the input file.

Comment: "This code I wrote stops at fscanf(f1, "%d", &n); and does not take any input in." Couldn't reproduce in my local environment (Windows 7 x64, GCC 4.8.1). What is your input file? Mine are [`in1.txt`](http://codepad.org/sKa46Yib) and [`in2.txt`](http://codepad.org/YmG2vwaW).

Comment: I took the teacher's example that he compiled in class and tried the run that, however, it does not let me do any scanning as well. It stops after I create the file.

Comment: I edited the document with the teacher's example as well. Could it be something I am doing that is causing this to happen? The teacher had no trouble in class with the code I downloaded from the course's webpage scanning in input. @MikeCAT

Comment: What do you mean by "stop"? Segmentation Fault? Freeze? Exit with no error? Also are there any reason you don't want to disclose your input data?

Comment: Your code works for me when using input data that matches that described by the code. You should post a small sample of your data, because it's possible that the input does not match the expectations of the code. Also, add debug statements to your code, print out what you read for `n` and for `SSN` and `wage` each time around the loop. This might give you the insight needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Also, you are supposed to write the _average_ wage to the file, so you need to divide `wage_total` by `n`, ie. `fprintf(f2,"%f", wage_total/n);`

Comment: If your code fails to open `f1`, it will be set to `NULL`. `fscanf()` will then result in `EBADF`. Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: In the teacher's code, `fp2` is opened and closed but otherwise unused; it serves no purpose in that code.  In your code, you write an answer to `f2`, so it serves a useful purpose.